# Connect Spring boot with Amazon RDS PostgreSQL

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, amazon-web-services, spring-boot

I am getting `Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource` and `connect timed out` errors while trying to connect to a locally running Spring boot application with PostgreSQL database instance running on Amazon AWS.

This is how my `application.properties` file look like:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://db_endpoint_here:5432/db_name_here
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username= db_username_here
spring.datasource.password= db_password_here

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

Am I doing it right?
Any suggestions to fix the connection time out error would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would start by checking the security group of the RDS instance. Also, is your Spring app running locally, or in AWS, in the same VPC as the RDS instance?

Comment: I am running it locally. This is the security info for RDS instance (Connectivity & security): `Security
VPC security groups: securedappvpc (sg-094f2119af29d6ba0)`, `Publicly accessible: Yes`, `Active`, `Publicly accessible: Yes`

Comment: Posting the security group ID does not provide us the "security info". Please look at the rules in the security group to see if the port is open for the appropriate IP address you are trying to connect from.

Answer (score 0):

For timeout issue, these are the changed in Security Groups you need:[AWS RDS Security Groups screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyFKS.png)

Also, make sure your for the AWS RDS its publicly accessible= Yes & you have given a DB name(its not mandatory while creating, but for connection it causes issues & cannot be updated once DB Instance is created).